# @OneToMany relationship property not filled

Tags: jpa, jpql, named-query, table-per-subclass

I have implemented *Joined, Multiple Table Inheritance*.

There is a 'parent' table *pois* and two sub tables: *xPois* and *yPois* and in turn I have an abstract *PoiDao* class as well as a *XPoiDao* and a *YPoiDao* class extending *PoiDao*.

A poi may have multiple reservations but a reservation belongs to exactly one poi.

Named queries defined in the child table DAOs work well for attributes defined in the respective (direct) table hierarchy. The parent table has a foreign key relationship to another table named *reservations* (table *reservations* holds the foreign key of table *pois*). The problem is that the records from this *reservations* table get not fetched.

Running this SQL statement in MySql Workbench gets the desired resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM xPois pp 
    LEFT JOIN pois p ON pp.poiId = p.poiId 
    LEFT JOIN reservations r ON p.poiId = r.poiId 
    WHERE pp.xPoiId = '2011';
```

In Eclipse I can see *{IndirectList: not instantiated}* when I inspect the xDao instance in debug mode.

How can I get the records from this table being stored in the PoiDao using JPA?

```
public abstract class PoiDao implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="poiId")
    private Integer poiId;

    @OneToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="addressId",insertable=true,
    updatable=true, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private AddressDao address;

    @Embedded
    private GeoLocationDao geoLocation;

    @Convert("poiTypeConverter")
    private ServiceTypeEnum poiType;
    @Column(name="operator")
    private String operator;

    @Column(name="reservable")
    private boolean reservable;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="poiId", insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private List<ReservationDao>    existingReservations;
    ...
    }

@Entity
@Table(name="xPois")
@DiscriminatorValue("X")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="XPoiDao.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM XPoiDao p"), 
    @NamedQuery(name="XPoiDao.findByXPoiId", 
                query="SELECT pp FROM XPoiDao pp LEFT JOIN PoiDao p ON pp.poiId = p.poiId "
                        + "LEFT JOIN ReservationDao r ON p.poiId = r.poiId WHERE pp.xPoiId = :xPoiId")
})
@ObjectTypeConverters({
    @ObjectTypeConverter (
            name="xPoiStatusConverter",
            dataType=java.lang.String.class,        // type in DB
            objectType=XPoiStatusEnum.class,    // Java type
            conversionValues={
                @ConversionValue(dataValue="FREE", objectValue="FREE"),
                @ConversionValue(dataValue="OCCUPIED BY VALUE", objectValue="OCCUPIED_BY_VALUE"),
                @ConversionValue(dataValue="OCCUPIED MANUALLY", objectValue="OCCUPIED_MANUALLY"),
                @ConversionValue(dataValue="BLOCKED", objectValue="BLOCKED")
            }
    )
})
public class XPoiDao extends PoiDao implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2496267921294255723L;

//  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer             id;

    @Column(name="xPoiId")
    private String              xPoiId;

    @Convert("xPoiStatusConverter")
    @Column(name="status")
    private XPoiStatusEnum status;

    @Embedded
    private ContactDao          contact;

//  @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//  @JoinColumn(name="poiId",insertable=true,updatable=true)
//  private List<ReservationDao>    existingReservations;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parkingPoiId",insertable=true,updatable=true)
    private List<OperatingHourDao> operatingHours;
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `FetchType.LAZY` in there. Do you get an empty list when you try to access it? Debuggers might not trigger the fetch requests.

Comment: Well, that did the trick. :)) 
I have several other @OneTomany relationships defined equally:
 
 @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="parkingPoiId",insertable=true,updatable=true)
 private List<OperatingHourEntity> operatingHours;

I don't have the problem there. The only difference: those tables are related directly to the sub tables/classes.

Comment: Removing the fetchtype shouldn't be necessary, though. Does it work if you attempt to access it (with the fetchtype specified)?

Comment: I set the fetch type fo reservations to EAGER and now it works. Thanks a lot.